# Printing an image using bbpos printer

Tags: android, service, printing, bluetooth

I want to print an receipt using bbpos printer in android. I am able to print text properly but not image.

I have taken a drawable image and converted into byte array but it prints some random characters but not the image I think I need to convert it again bitmap and than send it to printer.

Here is my code

```
public class PrintingService {

private static byte[] INIT = {0x1B, 0x40};
private static byte[] POWER_ON = {0x1B, 0x3D, 0x01};
private static byte[] NEW_LINE = {0x0A};
private static byte[] ALIGN_LEFT = {0x1B, 0x61, 0x00};
private static byte[] ALIGN_CENTER = {0x1B, 0x61, 0x01};
private static byte[] EMPHASIZE_ON = {0x1B, 0x45, 0x01};
private static byte[] EMPHASIZE_OFF = {0x1B, 0x45, 0x00};
private static byte[] FONT_5X12 = {0x1B, 0x4D, 0x01};
private static byte[] FONT_8X12 = {0x1B, 0x4D, 0x02};
private static byte[] FONT_10X18 = {0x1B, 0x4D, 0x03};
private static byte[] FONT_SIZE_0 = {0x1D, 0x21, 0x00};
private static byte[] FONT_SIZE_1 = {0x1D, 0x21, 0x11};
private static byte[] CHAR_SPACING_0 = {0x1B, 0x20, 0x00};
private ArrayList<VehicleInfo> mVehileInfo;
private double mTotal;
private Drawable mDrawable;

public PrintingService(Drawable drawable, ArrayList<VehicleInfo> vehicleInfo, double total)
{
    mVehileInfo = vehicleInfo;
    mTotal = total;
    mDrawable = drawable;
}

public byte[] getData() throws IOException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
    byte[] dataToPrint = null;
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    writeHeader(baos);

    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)mDrawable).getBitmap();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    dataToPrint = baos.toByteArray();




    return dataToPrint;
}

private void writeHeader(ByteArrayOutputStream baos) throws IOException {

    baos.write(INIT);
    baos.write(POWER_ON);
    baos.write(NEW_LINE);
    baos.write(ALIGN_CENTER);
    baos.write(FONT_SIZE_1);
    baos.write(EMPHASIZE_ON);
    baos.write(FONT_5X12);
    baos.write(CHAR_SPACING_0);
    baos.write("Print Demo".getBytes());
    baos.write(NEW_LINE);
    baos.write(NEW_LINE);
    baos.write("Sparken IT Solutions".getBytes());
    baos.write(NEW_LINE);
    baos.write("Surya Plaza".getBytes());
    baos.write(NEW_LINE);
    baos.write("Pune-411030".getBytes());
    baos.write(EMPHASIZE_OFF);
    baos.write(NEW_LINE);

}

private void writeRow(ByteArrayOutputStream baos, String tag, String value) throws IOException {
    if (!ValidationUtils.isStringNull(value)) {

        baos.write(EMPHASIZE_ON);
        baos.write(FONT_10X18);
        baos.write(tag.getBytes());
        baos.write(value.getBytes());
        baos.write(NEW_LINE);
        baos.write(EMPHASIZE_OFF);
    }

   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of bbpos you are using, however I believe as of version 3.4+ there is a BBDeviceController.getImageCommand(Bitmap) method.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for.